# Why some stack trace have negative line number?

Tags: java

When debugging the application and working with stack traces, I noticed that some lines of the stack trace have negative numbers. Usually in classes that are decompiled. Why is that? Example:

```
invoke0 NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java -2 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl
```

Comment: It could be caused by the obfuscator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A value of -2 indicates that the method containing the execution point is a native method

-1 means that the line number information is not available, for some reason. As you already noticed this is usually a case for classes from libs.

Source: [Java 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html#StackTraceElement-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-)